# How to move Checkout button to the bottom of minicart

Tags: magento2, template, mini-cart

I've been trying to move the "Go to check button" to the bottom of the minicart, as [this example](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html) but I have had no success.

I've done this kind of changes in ver.1.9.1 with no problem. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the content.html file inside your theme directory.

**app/design/frontend/{{PackageName}}/{{themename}}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html**

Here you can change the minicart as per your own design.

Comment: How to do this in custom module not theme ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `<Magento_Checkout_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html`

Here you can rearrange it according to your preference

It is specified and cleared in Magento developer documentation. please go through this

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-sample.html